# How to customize id of Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Using phoenix framework, `:id, :integer` would be generated automatically.
http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-custom-primary-keys

But I want it not auto-generated and use custom id field, for example `:id, :string`, much like this 
http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/

To set the

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Item do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  # @primary_key {:id, :id, autogenerate: false}
  schema "items" do
    field :id, :string, autogenerate: false # some unique id string
    field :type, :integer
```

It raises `** (ArgumentError) field/association :id is already set on schema` https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/db1f9ccdcc01f5abffcab0b5e0732eeecd93aa19/lib/ecto/schema.ex#L1327

Comment: it seems `create table(:items, primary_key: false) do` in migration file...? http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-custom-primary-keys

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two problems I was facing.

1. Both of `@primary_key {:id, :id, autogenerate: false}` and `fields :id` clause cannot be in schema definition.

This is the solution

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Item do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  @primary_key {:id, :string, []}
  schema "items" do
    # field :id, :string <- no need!
```

2. to avoid auto-generated id, I just have to edit migration file

Like this

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateItem do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:items, primary_key: false) do
      add :id, :string, primary_key: true
```

Finally, I can execute `mix ecto.migrate` and can get table definition below

```sql
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE items;
| items | CREATE TABLE `builds` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

Official document certainly says about that
http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/ecto-custom-primary-keys

> Let's take a look at the migration first, priv/repo/migrations/20150908003815_create_player.exs. We'll need to do two things. The first is to pass in a second argument - primary_key: false to the table/2 function so that it won't create a primary_key. Then we'll need to pass primary_key: true to the add/3 function for the name field to signal that it will be the primary_key instead.

But at the beginning, you don't want column `id`, you just do `create table(:items, primary_key: false)` in migration, and edit schema

```rb
defmodule MyApp.Item do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  # @primary_key {:id, :string, []}
  @primary_key false # to avoid unnecessary IO scanning
  schema "items" do
    # field :id, :string <- no need!
```

Though self-resolved, thanks anyway

Comment: If setting the custom primary id at migration, why not setting in the schema? Will it make unavailable the id for further queries, say with absinthe (graphql)? @otiai10

Comment: May I ask how do you set the `id` value? In the controller or inside the model definition?

Comment: @StevenV It was so project-specific solution and just the very beginning of my project, so I used just migration to change (as I remember). Defining it in the schema might work, I guess.

Comment: @W.M. I used some string from external service (e.g. MongoDB ObjectID from other service), therefore it was in the controller (as I remember. Sorry it was a long time ago when I was working on Phoenix)

Comment: @otiai10, I have managed to set it in the model class using `put_change`. Phoenix is very promising, it performs well. Have you found some other framework faster/better to work with?